# ADB stucks on my Android smart phone

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb, galaxy

After connecting my device to my real device (Galaxy S / Android 2.3.3) and lauching the DDMS Heap tab, sometimes the device disconnects and is no longer available as vaild Android target for the Android Device Chooser dialog. Un- and re-plugging the USB cable have no effect, killing the adb server process or shut down eclipse does not either. As my last resort I've to reboot the device and re-connect USB, this seems to work but this approach has a lot wrinkles, if you know what i mean.

Is there a better solution available?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about it. It's a known issue with all Android Phones based on the OMAP chipset.

It's not that the chipset is bad in any way, but it is fact that the USB-OTG device driver from OMAP is buggy. The driver works well until you stress it hard enough. Lots of logcat outputs cause this, as well as ADB debugging.

Disabling and re-enabling the usb-debug fixes the problem for a while. You can even see the USB-driver failing on the kernel-log by calling 'dmesg' on the shell.

As far as I know all OMAP3 and OMAP4 based devices suffer from this driver-bug.

Comment: Ouch.  I suppose using USB adb to turn on TCP adb before an involved debugging session might be something to consider.